# "fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory" using make

Tags: compiling, gtk, make

I am trying to use make command to build. I am following [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Hello-World). I am compiling a code using GTK+2 and C language

```
hp@ubuntu:~/amhello$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/hp/amhello'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/hp/amhello/src'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -g -O2 -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo -c -o         main.o main.c
main.c:3:20: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/hp/amhello/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hp/amhello'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

this is the main.c code

```
#include<config.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
void static call(GtkWidget *widget,gpointer data) {
    g_print("%s \n",(gchar*) data);
}
int main(int agrc, char *agrv[]) {
    gtk_init(&agrc,&agrv);
    GtkWidget *window,*button;
    window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(window,"delete-event",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"one button");
    button=gtk_button_new_with_label("hello world");
    g_signal_connect(button,"clicked",G_CALLBACK(call),(gpointer) "hello world");
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window),10);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),button);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: did you even check if the file is there as it states? /gtk/gtk.h

Comment: @Xylo dont know how to check. please tell me how i can check

Comment: check if directory `/usr/include/gtk-2.0` exists

Comment: @Baraiam i have added the content of main.c

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This means that you don't have the gtk headers to build stuff using GTK+. Is really weird that the error didn't showed up at ./configure step. To solve this just do:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

or `libgtk-3-dev`.

That should do it.

Comment: i have compiled several codes using #include<gtk/gtk.h> library

Comment: the problem is when i am trying to use command make

Comment: can you add the relevant code then to see if is possible to reproduce?

Comment: my compilies perfectly when i compile it by using this command gcc main.c -o hello `gtk-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`

Comment: go to this link and you will understand what i am trying to do http://askubuntu.com/questions/397246/makefile448-missing-separator-stop-error

Answer (score 14):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential gnome-devel
```

That is also needed so that you can do cool things like:

```
g++ main.cpp -o base `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

It allows you to use `pkg-config` to save a whole lot of time

Comment: At least in my case, I did not have to execute `sudo apt-get install build-essential gnome-devel`, and the second command seemed to work at first, but led to glib "No such file or directory" problems as well. Solution was more like: `g++ \`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0\` main.cpp -o base \`pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0\``

Answer (score 3):

Gtk3 equivalent debian/ubuntu package is `libgtk-3-dev`

Comment: Exactly works on debian buster. After install this library bellow command can compile simple source code to ./helloworld executable.
`gcc \`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0\` -o helloworld helloworld.c \`pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0\``

Answer (score 3):

In CentOS 7:
a) packages:

```
pkg-config --list-all|grep gtk
...
gtk+-3.0                  GTK+ - GTK+ Graphical UI Library
...
gtk+-2.0                  GTK+ - GTK+ Graphical UI Library (x11 target)
...
```

b) editing header section of your snippet:

```
#include<config.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
```

to

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
```

c) compiling using:

```
gcc main.c -o main `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

or

```
gcc main.c -o main `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

and

d) executing using:

```
GDK_SCALE=5 ./main
```

worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using autotools to generate your Makefiles, you need to tell automake how to find the header and library dependencies of your project and incorporate them into the final Makefiles. **This is not my area of expertise but I will try to point you in the right direction.** Most of the following is based on the tutorial found at [Using C/C++ libraries with Automake and Autoconf](http://www.openismus.com/documents/linux/using_libraries/using_libraries.shtml#cflagsandlibs)

First, you must modify the top level configure.ac file to add the Gtk-2.0 dependency. You can use the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro to run `pkg-config` to find the corresponding include and library directives - it's good practice to check that `pkg-config` exists first, so we should add a `PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG` test as well. **The bolded portions indicate what`s added, relative to the files in the original amhello tutorial that you started from.**

```
AC_INIT([amhello], [1.0], [bug-automake@gnu.org])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
 Makefile
 src/Makefile
])
dnl Test for pkg-config
PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG([0.22])
dnl Test for gtk+
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([GTK], [gtk+-2.0 >= 2.24.10])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Then in your `src/Makefile.am` you can retrieve the CFLAGS and LIBS using the `GTK` identifier that you used in the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro above

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello
hello_SOURCES = main.c
AM_CPPFLAGS = ${GTK_CFLAGS}
hello_LDADD = ${GTK_LIBS}
```

When you re-run `make`, it should re-generate your src/Makefile with the appropriate `-I` include paths, `-L` library paths and libraries.

Comment: you are a genius. i was just waiting for your answer because i knew you can give the appropriate answer. thanks :)