# gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory (Make 4.1, Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gtk, make

I'm trying to use a make file for `xnee`, and everything was going smooth for its install until the end when the mentioned error occurred.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397432/fatal-error-gtk-gtk-h-no-such-file-or-directory-using-make) said to try either to install `libgtk2.0-dev` or `libgtk-3-dev`, but neither of them resolved the issue.

Is there a newer GTK version that I should be using? The version of `xnee` I'm trying to use is 3.19, released in 2014-- those GTK versions should be perfectly fine.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with a MATE Desktop environment.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *"use a make file for xnee"*? if you mean that you are trying to `./configure` and `make` xnee-3.19 from source, please include the output of `grep gtk config.log Makefile`

Comment: config.log:configure:5323: checking for gtk-config
config.log:gtk_CFLAGS=''
config.log:gtk_LIBS=''
Makefile:gtk_CFLAGS = 
Makefile:gtk_LIBS =

Comment: Is the `pkg-config` package installed on your system?

Comment: Yes, and it's at the latest version.

Comment: So what does `pkg-config --modversion gtk+-{2,3}.0` report?

Comment: What are you hoping to gain building instead of just installing xnee from Ubuntu repos? (./configure/make works fine here on 18.04..

Comment: What was wrong with [binary packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=xnee) from *universe* pocket?

Comment: @steeldriver Package gtk+2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+2.0' found
Package gtk+3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+3.0' found

Comment: @doug Oddly, it told me that the package didn't exist.

Comment: Post result of `apt-cache policy xnee`  If nothing is shown then output of `sudo apt update`